# Yodlee MFA site flow

Tags: refresh, yodlee

The yodlee documentation about the MFA flow is a bit blurry/outdated.

I am following this flow chart to refresh a site with MFA: http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Site_Account

On the flow chart, after calling getMFAResponseForSite, we are supposed to check if there is an `errorCode` field in the response, I don't see such field in [the documentation of the getMFAResponseForSite method](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponseForSite). Because without this error code field, we cannot go back into the regular flow and wait for the refresh to be completed.

Also what is the difference between `retry` and `isMessageAvailable`?

The documentation specify to call [stopSiteRefresh](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/stopSiteRefresh) method, I don't see it in the flow, it sounds weird for me to call it but the documentation says:

`Note that this is one of the APIs that is required to refresh MFA accounts.`

Can somebody give me a clear flow when I have to deal with MFA sites? when and how can we go back on the regular process (getSiteRefreshInfo) and wait for the end of the refresh? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "errorCode" field only comes when there is no MFA question available and hence you are not seeing it in the sample of the API documentation as the sample contains the response with MFA question.

If you follow the flow closely you can see that you have to call getMFAResponseForSite in a loop and check for errorCode. So please call the API as depicted in the API flow documentation.

Here is a sample with errorCode field present after successfully answering the MFA question.

> {
>     "isMessageAvailable": true,
>     "fieldInfo": {
>       "questionAndAnswerValues": [],
>       "numOfMandatoryQuestions": -1,
>       "mfaFieldInfoType": "SECURITY_QUESTION"
>     },
>     "timeOutTime": 97690,
>     "itemId": 0,
>     "errorCode": 0,
>     "memSiteAccId": xxxxxxxxxx,
>     "retry": false
>   }

Please also ignore the stopSiteRefresh API call, we will rectify the API reference documentation, as that API call should not be made in case of getMFAResponseForSite API.